# Pandas read_csv into multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in text file that I am reading into Pandas. A simplified version of the txt read in is:

```
idx_level1|idx_level2|idx_level3|idx_level4|START_NODE|END_NODE|OtherData...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:26Z|1|18260004567689|18260005575180|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:26Z|2|18260004567689|18260004240718|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:26Z|3|18260005359901|18260004567689|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:31Z|1|18260004567689|18260005575180|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:31Z|2|18260004567689|18260004240718|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:31Z|3|18260005359901|18260004567689|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:36Z|1|18260004567689|18260005575180|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:36Z|2|18260004567689|18260004240718|...
353386066294006|1142|2018-09-20T07:57:36Z|3|18260005359901|18260004567689|...
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:23Z||||...
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:24Z||||...
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:25Z||||...
353386066736543|22|2018-04-17T07:08:26Z||||...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|1|18260004580350|18260005235340|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|2|18260005235340|18260005141535|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|3|18260005235340|18260005945439|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|4|18260006215338|18260005235340|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|5|18260004483352|18260005945439|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:07Z|6|18260004283163|18260006215338|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|1|18260004580350|18260005235340|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|2|18260005235340|18260005141535|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|3|18260005235340|18260005945439|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|4|18260006215338|18260005235340|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|5|18260004483352|18260005945439|...
353386066736543|403|2018-07-02T16:55:01Z|6|18260004283163|18260006215338|...
```

And the code I use to read in is as follows:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('/myloc/my_simple_data.txt', sep='|', 
 dtype={'idx_level1': 'int',
        'idx_level2': 'int',
        'idx_level3': 'str',
        'idx_level4': 'float',
        'START_NODE': 'str',
        'END_NODE': 'str',
        'OtherData...': 'str'},
parse_dates = ['idx_level3'],
index_col=['idx_level1','idx_level2','idx_level3','idx_level4'])
```

What I really want to do is have a seperate panadas DataFrames for each unique  `idx_level1` & `idx_level2` value. So in the above example there would be 3 DataFrames pertaining to `idx_level1|idx_level2` values of `353386066294006|1142`,  `353386066736543|22` & `353386066736543|403` respectively.

Is it possible to read in a text file like this and output each change in idx_level2 to a new Pandas DataFrame, maybe as part of some kind of loop? Alternatively, what would be the most efficient way to split `mydata` into DataFrame subsets, given that everything I have read suggests that it is inefficient to iterate through a DataFrame.

Comment: This looks like something where `DataFrame.groupby` function would work

Comment: Hey N.P. I looked at that - but all examples I've show aggregation of the data rather than splitting. I.e. it would be find if I wanted to find say the max value of START_NODE and END_NODE. How would you use Groupby to just subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your dataframe as you are currently doing then groupby and use list comprehension:

```
group = mydata.groupby(level=[0,1])
dfs = [group.get_group(x) for x in group.groups]
```

you can call your dataframes by doing `dfs[0]` and so on

Answer (score 0):

To specifically address your last paragraph, you could create a dict of dfs, based on unique values in the column using something like:

```
import copy
dict = {}
cols = df[column].unique()

for value in col_values:
    key = 'df'+str(value)
    dict[key] = copy.deepcopy(df)
    dict[key] = dict[key][df[column] == value]
    dict[key].reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
```

where column = `idx_level2`

Comment: Thanks BAC83 - 3 questions, 1) Just to make sure I understand this, I think you are creating a dictionary that contains a series of values paris - the name of a dataframe, and the datarrame itself - is that correct? 2) should `for value in col_values:` read `for value in cols:`?  3) Could this be made to work with a combination of my first 2 columns i.e. idx_level1|idx_level2, as idx_level2 could be the same over different idx_level1 values.?

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) Yes (sorry - I pulled in some old code and attempted editing for clarity) and 3)... not sure

Answer (score 0):

Read the table as-it-is and use `groupby`, for instance:

```
data = pd.read_table('/myloc/my_simple_data.txt', sep='|')
groups = dict()
for group, subdf in data.groupby(data.columns[:2].tolist()):
    groups[group] = subdf
```

Now you have all the sub-data frames in a dictionary whose keys are a tuple of the two indexers (eg: `(353386066294006, 1142)`)

Comment: Can also use list comprehensions and do a one-liner: `groups = dict((k, v) for k, v in data.groupby(data.columns[:2].tolist()))
`